# Will taking up a job in the enterpise s/w domain reduce my chances of later shifting to consumer software?

Tags: enterprise-development, junior-programmer

I have been offered a job from campus in the Enterprise s/w domain. I'm at loggerheads with myself deciding if I should take up the job, since I'm generally interested in consumer s/w esp in companies that encourage open source contributions. My question is if i'll find it difficult to later(maybe after a year or two) change my domain and move onto B2C (Business to Consumer) software companies. Will my past experience with enterprise software stand against me?

Comment: Hi amal antony, speculative career advice like this is off-topic because we don't know you: we don't know what opportunities await you or what companies might think of your resume; the best thing you can do is talk to friends and colleagues about your specific situation and see what they say.

Comment: Hello Mark, I thought my question was quite general to be answered here. It's something that can apply to any fresh graduate aint it? So I request you reopen the question. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

**That fact that you worked in an Enterprise domain won’t be counted as a negative BUT the fact that you haven’t been working in B2C will.** *“No recent experience with public facing web apps?“*

The same thing will happen if you take a job doing B2C then want to switch to B2B. B2B companies will hold the lack of Client facing experience against you.

Comment: I don't get it. Clients aren't people?

Answer (score 1):

It depends a lot on the company you're applying to. Some only want people with a very specific background, such as specific work experience and a specific degree. Other, better, more open minded, companies understand that programming talent is programming talent and that innovative ideas and great work can come from people outside of a very narrow subset.

Answer (score 1):

if you plan to switch early on in your career it wont matter much, in fact it would probably help you to list some relevant experience to software development. just don't expect to get a job that requires X years of experience in consumer software with X years of experience something else, though you would still likely be qualified for jobs that require X-Y experience

Answer (score 0):

You could find yourself working with a technology that is not popular (You mentioned ABAP and how non-enterprise jobs won't use that), but you should be 90% what you'll be using during the hiring process.

The other concern is how your personality will fit in with the corporate cultures. There is a stereo-type that programmers working in non-software related industries and typically larger companies are not a fit for smaller, flexible, cutting-edge (younger) company cultures.

It will really depend on you.